# Can you make AppExchange app functionality available to Communities users?

Tags: community, appexchange

I'm researching if it would be possible to give Communities users access to Apttus quoting capability and I can't find much about managed packages and Communities at all beyond seeing that custom objects which are part of managed packages don't count toward the custom object limit of 10 custom objects per a Communities license user profile.

Can Partner Community users be licensed for paid AppExchange apps like Apttus? Assuming that they're given access to all the necessary objects, VF pages, and Apex classes, is there any reason they couldn't use the app like a normal internal user?

Comment: You can customize using Apttus API's